# ORA-01654: unable to extend index SYS.I_IDL_UB11 by 8 in tablespace SYSTEM 00604. 00000 - "error occurred at recursive SQL level %s"

Tags: oracle

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1

ORA-01654: unable to extend index SYS.I_IDL_UB11 by 8 in tablespace SYSTEM
00604. 00000 -  "error occurred at recursive SQL level %s"

*Cause:    An error occurred while processing a recursive SQL statement
           (a statement applying to internal dictionary tables).
*Action:   If the situation described in the next error on the stack
           can be corrected, do so; otherwise contact Oracle Support.
```

**for the below program**

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_job(a VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HELLO '||a);
END;
/
```

Comment: Do **NOT** create your own procedures, tables, view or anything else using the SYSTEM user. Create a regular user and create the procedure using that user. Do **NOT** use the SYSTEM (or SYS) account for that.

Comment: Thanks. It is raising due to lack of space

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `SYS.I_IDL_UB11` is built in. Seems to be part of compiled PL/SQL code storage. I guess the SYSTEM tablespace is full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks as if your SYSTEM tablespace has not enough space to extend the index segment. I would take a look at dba_data_files and compare blocks, maxblocks, user_blocks for the system tablespace, and check the value for AUTOEXTENSIBLE.

Since there is not much you can do to shrink the SYSTEM tablespace (apart from maybe get rid of audit data) usually a massive growth of the SYSTEM tablespace indicates a problem (maybe indeed some user objects in the tablespace).